# What is the solid angle in higher dimensions?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I'm struggling with understanding the generalization of a solid angle to higher dimensions. What is the intuition behind a solid angle in general and how does it generalize in higher dimensions?

Edit: One thing that is not very clear to me:

For 3D space $d\Omega = \dfrac{dS}{r^2}$ so the solid angle is the ratio of the area subtended to the square of the radius, how can I write the n dimensional infinitesimal solid angle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You generalize by generalizing the notation. Let $dS$ be the surface "area" $(n-1)$-form on $\Bbb R^n-\{0\}$ which gives the "area" on the unit sphere. And then you set $d\Omega = \dfrac{dS}{r^{n-1}}$ as an $(n-1)$-form on $\Bbb R^n-\{0\}$. Integrating this over a chunk of hypersurface in $\Bbb R^n$ gives the solid angle it subtends. (And yes, one can write down explicit formulas.)

Answer (score 3):

This definition from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) generalizes:

> In geometry, a solid angle (symbol: Ω) is a measure of the amount of
> the field of view from some particular point that a given object
> covers. That is, it is a measure of how large the object appears to an
> observer looking from that point. The point from which the object is
> viewed is called the apex of the solid angle, and the object is said
> to subtend its solid angle from that point.

Center a unit sphere at the vertex of the angle and calculate the fraction of the $n-1$-dimensional surface area of the sphere your angle cuts off.

**Edit** in response to comment.

In three dimensions:

To find the solid angle subtended by a rectangular plate you need the coordinates of the vertices and the coordinates of the point $P$ you're looking from. Project the vertices from $P$ onto the surface of a unit sphere centered at $P$. Joint those vertices to form a quadrilateral on the sphere with edges sections of great circles. Then find the area of that quadrilateral (as a fraction of the area of the sphere). I think this will call for a fair amount of [spherical trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry).  Also see [Area of Spherical Polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228964/area-of-spherical-polygon)

For a weird surface you'll have to find a way to find it's weird projection onto the sphere, and then the area of the projection.

Comment: I sort of see it now, but I think if you answer the following two extremes I think I would have a solid understanding:

(1) Suppose you have a convoluted nonuniform weird surface how do you find the solid angle subtended by such a surface?

(2) How do you find the solid angle subtended by a rectangular plane?

Comment: @LostInEuclids5thPostulate See my edit.